# USB extender using Cat5/5e/6 with Male USB on both ends

Tags: usb

I am looking for a male-to-male USB extender to connect an older USB 2.0-only printer and a desktop. There is a 40ft gap between the two. Running between those is an unused Cat 5e cable  (I think it's 5e, I haven't verified yet).   They simply want to connect the printer to the computer so the obvious answer is to just terminate each end of the available Cat5e cable with USB extenders.

However, when I search for USB extenders over cat5/cat5e/cat6, every single one that I find has a male USB-to-network adapter and a female USB-to-network adapter. Yet, every use-case I can think of where you would want a USB cable extended over cat5/5e/6 would ultimately want male USB connectors on both ends.

Sure, I can buy a male/female extender, which would have the 3 obvious components (female USB-to-network + network cable + male USB-to-network), and then add a fourth component which is a typical male-to-male cable. But that's adding another point of failure and potentially bothersome signal degradation into the system.

Maybe the problem is I am searching for "extender" and I should be searching for some other term?

Comment: How far are you trying to send this signal? Do you already have the cable laid? In any case I'd argue the normal use case (since it's an extender, as though you just moved your port) is male to female, but ignoring that, what's wrong with just another male to male bit? Signal degradation isn't an issue since it'll be a short run well within spec and it's a digital connection, and quite frankly, I wouldn't worry about another point of failure; it's a USB cable for goodness sake.

Comment: If you can you give us your use case and a few requirements, we might be able to help you look for the product you want.

Comment: I updated it the question with the use case.  It's nothing tricky, I just wondered if someone could shed light on why male-to-male extenders aren't the norm, since in nearly every case you are almost always dealing with female terminated equipment.  Or maybe they do exist but I just don't know what the proper search term is.   Hmm, now I am thinking I should have tried "usb to cat5 converters" or something.  I'll do that now.

Comment: As for the second cable: much of the time that cable/whatever will already be embedded into the thing you're plugging in. Think of a (cheap) keyboard or mouse or USB hub or whatever: having a port on the other end is just more flexible.